# Using formation config file with pyrocms module

Tags: pyrocms

I'm building a site using Pyrocms and am using the Formation class for creating my forms. I'm creating a module and would like to put my formation.php file in the modules config folder, but when I do I get the following error message:

> addons/modules/projects/config/formation.php
>   does not contain a valid config array

The form works fine if I put the form definition in system/pyrocms/config/formation.php, but I'd like to keep it in my module folder.

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to put that in the main pyrocms config folder.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks for the confirmation, Phil.